# React Native get TextInput value and use on the same View using onBlur or onFocus method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I would like to get the value from a TextInput picker (using react-native-material-dropdown) and perform calculations on close of dropdown using the blur method, the dropdown is numeric.

```
<Dropdown
        label='meals'
        data={data}
        onChangeText={this.onRegularMealChange.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.regularMeal}
      />
```

would like to do something like:

```
<View>
          <Text>{amount * this.props.regularMeal}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I want the calculation in the View tag to take place when the picker is released

Comment: You shouldn't bind inside of `onChangeText` as `.bind` creates a new function. When you're changing text, you're creating a new function every time. You should bind in the constructor, or change `onRegularMealChange` to an arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my reducer.